# Logic behind php if code

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to understand this code in the company's system that I am working in but this doesn't make any sense for me.

```
$k = 48;

if (($k & 2) > 0) {

 echo "2 is true";
}

echo "<br />";
if (($k & 4) > 0) {
 echo "4 is true";
}

echo "<br />";
if (($k & 8) > 0) {
 echo "8 is true";
}
echo "<br />";
if (($k & 16) > 0) {
 echo "16 is true";
}
echo "<br />";
if (($k & 32) > 0) {
 echo "32 is true";
}
```

When $k is 10 or 11, both 2 and 8 is true.

When $k is 12 or 13, both 4 and 8 is true.

Please help me figure this out

Comment: What if you ask a developer who wrote it? PS: it's just a weirdly implementing bitmask comparison

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: @zerkms He doesn't work for the company anymore and he probably won't help me out

Comment: @AdamPlocher Thanks but still it doesn't make sense for me I already read that

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29 Do you understand binary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is simply checking if certain bit positions are set in some value `$k`. See how [bitwise airthmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators) works.

In the code you've sent us, it doesn't have much context. However, this is a typical pattern for checking values in a bitmask.

In general, however, the `> 0` is unnecessary (since anything `!0` typically `== true`).

It is important to note that when I say bit positions, I mean of the binary number. That is, `$k & 32` does not check bit number 32, it instead checks the 6th most significant bit (`32d == 0b100000`).

**Short example**

Consider the last statement. We already determined that decimal 32 looks like `100000` in binary. Now say that we want to check whether or not the 6th bit is set in some number 33. 33 is represented as `0b100001` in binary. Now we take the `bitwise and` which works much like multiplication that we're used to seeing in base 10 (i.e. decimal).

```
0b100000 <--- decimal 32
&
0b100001 <--- decimal 33
--------
0b100000 <--- Result is > 0 and, therefore, this value has the 6th bit set
```

Now, let's retry this example with a different number. How about decimal 15.

```
0b100000 <--- decimal 32
&
0b001111 <--- decimal 15
--------
0b000000 <--- Result == 0 and, therefore, the 6th bit is not set
```

Now, this `&` (not to be confused with `logical and` which is represented as `&&`) works for multiple bits as well. Say you want to check for bits 6 and 4, then you would want to use `0b101000` (decimal `40`), but depending on what you wanted to test (i.e. exactly those bits or just one of those bits), your conditional may change.

***Just a little bit more***
From a style standpoint it is important to note that these masks are typically represented in hexadecimal instead of decimal (or binary because that would be cumbersome). This is mostly because it is somewhat unclear what binary representation a decimal number correlates to when looking at it "at-a-glance." Let us again consider decimal 32. In hexadecimal, a binary number can be represented as a hexadecimal number by simply grouping bits by 4's (from right to left). See below

```
0b100000 <--- decimal 32
    0000  === 0x0 (hexadecimal 0)
  10      === 0b0010 (implied leading 0's) === 0x2 (hexadecimal 2)
--------
0x20
```

As you can see, hex 20 is decimal 32 is binary 100000.

Comment: Maybe you could add an example for the first 2 if statements how it looks like if you write the numbers in binary and do the bitwise AND operator, just to visualize this a bit more :D

Comment: @PierreOrtega wrote an example hope you see it better what's going on and how it works

Comment: @RageD Nice example it really helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

In your code there are just some bitwise AND operation which checks if some bits are set or not.

So if we take a look what's going on in the first one:

```
$k = 48;
```

```
if (($k & 2) > 0) {
    echo "2 is true";
}
```

The expression `($k & 2)` a bit more readable:

```
0011 0000   $k
0000 0010   2
------------ &
0000 0000      = 0
```

So `if (0 > 0)` is false

And another example:

```
if (($k & 16) > 0) {
    echo "16 is true";
}
```

The expression `($k & 16)` a bit more readable:

```
0011 0000   $k
0001 0000   16
------------ &
0001 0000      = 16
```

So `if (16 > 0)` is true

**FYI information:**

Bitwise AND operation table:

```
  A  |  B  | Result
--------------------
  0  |  0  |   0
  0  |  1  |   0
  1  |  0  |   0
  1  |  1  |   1
```

And as a reference to the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Thanks, now everything makes more sense.